# for loop in R behaves in unexpected way

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm writing this function and my loop is behaving in a different way. can you explain why it does this and how to correct?

```
    complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332)  {
    specd <- list.files("specdata", full.names = TRUE)
    temp<- vector(mode = "numeric", (length = length(id)))
    for (i in id)   {
    temp[i] <- nrow(na.omit(read.csv(specd[i])))
    }
    return(data.frame(id = id, nobs = temp))
    }
```

code:

```
complete("specdata", 1)OBSERVATION – id = 1; yields 1 answer
  id nobs
1  1  117
complete("specdata", 3) OBSERVATION – id = 3; yields 3 answers
  id nobs
1  3    0
2  3   NA
3  3  243
complete("specdata", 30:25) OBSERVATION – id = 30; yields 30 answers
complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
```

> Show Traceback   Rerun with Debug  Error in data.frame(id = id, nobs
>   = temp) :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 12

Comment: You need to give us something that we can paste in and execute.

Comment: `for (i in id)` should be `for (i in 1:id)`.

Comment: @RHertel, it is drawing the numbers correctly.

Comment: Then the loop seems to be perfectly unnecessary... It only checks the case `i=id`.

Comment: You are correct, `1:length(id)` would fix it. @RHertel.

Comment: It didn't work.  I get the following results:  complete("specdata", 1)
  id nobs
1  1  117
> complete("specdata", 3)
  id nobs
1  1  117
> complete("specdata", 23)
  id nobs
1  1  117
> complete("specdata", 30:25)
  id nobs
1  6  117
2  6 1041
3  6  243
4  6  474
5  6  402
6  6  228
> complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
  id nobs
1  5  117
2  5 1041
3  5  243
4  5  474
5  5  402

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332)  {
specd <- list.files("specdata", full.names = TRUE)
temp<- c()
for (i in id)   {
temp <- c(temp,nrow(na.omit(read.csv(specd[i]))))
}
return(data.frame(id = id, nobs = temp))
}
```

The reason you are getting mismatched row lengths is because `temp[i]` assigns the output to the ith placemark in temp. So when you try `c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12)`. You are expecting to get a vector of length five for `temp`. but you get a vector of length 12. Because `temp[12]` an element of the output. So `temp` is stretched out to that length. Example:

```
x <- 1
x
[1] 1
x[5] <- 2
x
[1]  1 NA NA NA  2
```

When I assigned a value to the fifth element of x, R expanded the vector without asking me to do the task.

complete("specdata", 3) returned 3 answers because `temp` initially had one value, `0`. You preassigned it at the beginning. Then the for loop assigned `243` to `temp[3]` as you instructed it to. So R filled in an NA value for the second value, and you were left with three.

```
  id nobs
1  3    0
2  3   NA
3  3  243
```

Comment: It didn't work.
When i changed it to this:
for (i in 1: length(id))   {
      temp[i] <- nrow(na.omit(read.csv(specd[id])))
 
I get the following good results with the single values but not the multiple values:

> complete("specdata", 1)
  id nobs
1  1  117
> complete("specdata", 3)
  id nobs
1  1  243
> complete("specdata", 23)
  id nobs
1  1  492
> complete("specdata", 30:25)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument > complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
 Show Traceback

Answer (score 0):

Change this lines in your code function to:

```
temp<- vector()
for (i in 1:length(id))
```