# converting list to data frame with specific column names in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've reviewed the other similar threads on here but haven't found the answer to my question yet. I'm building a list in a for loop that I want to convert to a data frame. The final list looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 117

[[2]]
[1] 1041

[[3]]
[1] 243

[[4]]
[1] 474

[[5]]
[1] 402
```

I want to convert this to a data frame, with specific column names: ID and nobs. So for example for 5th row in the data frame, the row value for ID would be 5 and the value for bobs would be 402. Running this code:

```
d <- data.frame(cbind(l))
```

gives me the columns but without the names. How and where can I specify the column names? I am just learning R. Thanks for any help.

this is the full code for my function:

```
complete <- function(directory, id) {
        files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
        l <- list()
        for (i in id){
                nobs <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_full[i])))
                l[i] <- nobs
        }
        d <- data.frame(cbind(l))
        d
}
```

Comment: `data.frame(id=seq(length(l)), nobs=do.call(rbind, l))`

Comment: Thanks! that does it for this case. But what if the values for my ID column were not numbers but something else, like a,b,c,d,e?

Comment: Are they in a separate list? or variable?

Comment: I will post my full code above - I just want to make sure I'm finding the best way to do it

Comment: Since each nob is one number you don't need a list. Make l a vector like `c()` or whatever your favorite method is and save nobs to that. And the id column is already provided from the user, there is no manipulation needed for that column.

Comment: Here's how others did that assignment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079500/error-in-drop-has-j-invalid-x-type-in-x-y-when-using-sumcomplete-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139879/for-loop-in-r-behaves-in-unexpected-way)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I see your answer in the first post, which makes sense, only when i create the data frame outside of the for loop, it returns the last nobs value for all rows in the final data frame

Comment: Nevermind I see where I went wrong, thx for all your help

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
l <- list(a=305,b=354,c=436,d=36)
> l
$a
[1] 305
$b
[1] 354
$c
[1] 436
$d
[1] 36

data.frame(id=names(l), nobs=unlist(l))
  id nobs
a  a  305
b  b  354
c  c  436
d  d   36
data.frame(l)
    a   b   c  d
1 305 354 436 36
unlist(l)
a   b   c   d 
305 354 436  36
```

Note that first and second are data.frame's, but last is named numeric vector.

---

Edit:

Probably you don't have any names in your list as in your example.
    I presume that you want to create named list and convert it to data.frame...
    If you want to set names to your list it should work:

```
complete <- function(directory, id) {
    files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    l <- vector(mode='list', length=length(files_full))
    for (i in files_full){
            nobs <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(i)))
            l[i] <- nobs
    }
    d <- data.frame(cbind(l))
    d
}
```

But let's try this:
    `sapply(list.files(), function(x)sum(complete.cases(read.csv(x))))`
It should return something like:

```
a.csv   b.csv    c.csv
 2153     326      235
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did actually try data.frame(id=names(l), nobs=unlist(l)), but it gave me an error:  `Error in data.frame(id = names(l), nobs = unlist(l)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 5`

Comment: Probably you don't have any names in your list as in your example.